# Skills Matrix on SharePoint 2013 Online

Tags: matrix, sharepoint-2013, ms-access-2013, sharepoint-online

I was asked to create a skills matrix for our company on SharePoint 2013 Online. Our company consists of about 400 employees.The skills matrix consists of 4 Categories with several fields under each category. Each field has three columns associated with it, Skill Level(1-5), When Last Used, Months Experience.

The goal:1. Fill out form on sharepoint.
2. Save to list- date created - created by 
3. HR logs on and pull all skills for specific user into excel.

What I have tried:1. InfoPath form that saves to list. Problem : Unable to add four different repeating tables to add all related skills for that user under each category.

2. InfoPath form that saves to library. Problem : Unable to query data for HR
3. MS Access 2013 web app. Problem : Unable to add more skills under each category.Unable to associate one user to several skills.

I think the best solution is probably to go with Access. if anyone could please point me in the right direction to go about this?

or even if there is a better way of coding a custom app in visual studio?